# How can get 90 day refresh token using Microsoft Graph authentication API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm using the [MSAL Browser library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/request-response-object.md#request) Login on js client with using acquireTokenSilent or acquireTokenPopup to get access token and refresh token.

The refresh token I'm getting is valid for 1 day as can be seeing on [refresh the access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token) section:
[image]

I want to change my login process to get a refresh token that will be valid for 90 days.
How is it possible?

My server is .NET Core.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to retain a refresh token for longer, you'll need to use the Authorization Code grant and store it server-side. The expiration of refresh tokens generated using the Implicit grant is fixed at 24 hours.

Comment: Hi, using the code grant flow I see that if I don't revoke the token for 24 hours I'm no longer able to get an access token. What should I do? Thanks!